# QMake, `.qmake.cache` with QMAKE_CXXFLAGS

Tags: qmake

In the `.qmake.cache` file in the root directory of my project, I do:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk
```

(Basically I followed the suggestions [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QMake-top-level-srcdir-and-builddir).)

The project consists of several orders of subdirs. When I manually go into some subdir and do `make`, it uses those CXXFLAGS. However, if I do `make` in the root directory, it does not add them.

Why? How can I fix that?

---

My current workaround:

- Never do `qmake` in a subdirectory. That seems to create other makefiles which seem to confuse `qmake` when run from the root.
- When you ended up with some bad makefiles or other bad state, remove all makefiles from all dirs and all QMake immediate files, and run `qmake` again in the root.

I'm not really happy with that. There is no real indication whether I am in a good state or not, because it also compiles without that `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` specification, only that the resulting binary might not load on older MacOSX versions, or even only parts of it at runtime, which I cannot even test so easily.